# Implent shanon fano or huffman codes in assembly without structures

Tags: assembly, compression, tasm, dosbox, lossless-compression

I'm learning assembly on `tasm` on `DOSBox` emulator. I need to do a project about 1500 code lines in length on a topic for my choosing. My idea is to try implenting a text comppression algorithm on assmebly with shanon fano  or huffman codes .I understand the general concept of both algorithms and I see they are closely connected to trees. For some reason we can't use structures in our code. So here is my question: can I build one of these algorithms in assembly without structures and without going through immense difficulty. I saw a few implementations of these algorithms online but I didn't find any implementation without structures that I can't use or oop that I don't have.

Thanks in advance.
Doron

Edit:
I still haven't figured out how to implement the struct as suggested in the comments. Any help or useful examples will be welcome.

Comment: Acordding to the comments its not huffman code or shanon fano.

Comment: Thats seems like a prefix code but non optimal one from what I can see.I am hoping a full huffman will be mroe code lines to meet the requiments.By the way I am not loking for a code in assembly I am looking for a code in c or in pseudo language.

Comment: The code will be wirtten in  assembly with its limitations.

Comment: Machine code doesn't know structures. Can you elaborate on your restrictions? I also recommend you to choose something else. Huffman codes can be a bit tedious to implement correctly.

Comment: You can implement structures in assembly without using any assembler support for structures pretty easily. Assembler support for structures tends to range from poor to non-existent anyways. It would however not be practical to create a compression algorithm that doesn't have something that someone can point to and say its a structure. As soon as you have two values located next to each other in memory you can call them a structure.

Comment: A huffman code could be implemented using an array (count of each character), then the code could be generated based on "popularity" without using any tree like structure, just two arrays for code size and code value, used to represent each character. I don't think this will take 1500 lines of code. Maybe if it was combined with LZ77 (LZ1) type compression, but still not 1500 lines of code.

Comment: @rcgldr I think you're going to need some sort of tree representation to efficiently generate an optimal code. Zlib's deflate algorithm uses a array to represent the tree, but it's still a tree with a `Dad` member indexing each element's parent element (node).

Comment: @RossRidge - True, but my main point is that I doubt this will take 1500 lines of assembly code.

Comment: If your restriction is about `STRUCT` directive of one infamous assembler, then forget it (like = no real restriction), you can build up almost the same thing with just `EQU` defining particular offsets from base address. I actually prefer it over `STRUCT` often, as I don't write anything big in asm any more, and the more raw it is, the less I have to remember about particular assembler directives/macro/other_bogus_stuff.

Comment: Is 1500 lines a requirement? 1500 lines is going to involve more than something like Huffman compression and decompression.

Comment: The code will involve decompression and maybe a bit of graphic for the ui.Most of the weight in the assignment is about the complexty of the project and relatively to other projects I am quite fine(pong, snake with "upgrades",minesweeper, and etc).Dose the "equ" keywors supprted by tasm and dos. and if so can anyone explain me a bit about it or send some info beacouse its the first time I hear about it. In the mean time thanks for the answers

Comment: Masm supports `EQU` in the same way as other assemblers. See [masm directives](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8t163bt0.aspx).

Comment: Can you provide me a link to a clear explansion about this directive and how to use it cause apart from syntex the msdn dosent tell me a lot about the directive.And I didnt find a lot about it online.

Comment: anyone  can help ?

Comment: Use EQU to associate a symbol with a value, such as `abc equ 1234`, so later in the code `abc` is the same as using 1234. If you wanted to replace a structure with a series of equates, the then values would be the offsets from the beginning of the structure.

Comment: I am afraid I still dont understand. I understand ho you can give a const symbol nd then you the symbol instead of the const.But I dont udnderstand how you can implent binary trees with that. Can you give me code example on how to use EQU to eumlute structres.